# Probability density function of Gaussian noise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, density-function

I am wondering if a probability density function on a stochastic process can be defined. I've been searching around but what I've seen so far are only finite-dimensional distributions of a stochastic process. What's I'm interested in is something else -- can a probability density function be defined on an infinite-dimensional space such as the samples of a stochastic process?

Until recently, I came across a paper which says that if $\eta(t)$ is a Gaussian noise process (i.e. white noise) such that $E[\eta(t)] = 0$ and $E[\eta(t) \eta(t')] = D \delta(t-t')$ then the "formal" probability density for this process is given by

$P(\eta(t)) \propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2D} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \eta^2 \,dt)$ for time points $t_i,t_f$.

I cannot find a reference for this and am unsure if the authors quoted "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals" by Feynman and Hibbs because the reference citation appeared to allude to a previous statement.

In any case, it appears that this density function was formulated by physicists. Can anyone direct me to mathematical papers which discuss this concept and how to make sense of it, somewhat more rigorously?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  What is a "formal" density function?  The spectrum (transform of the covariance) of this process is constant.  In your note, what is the definition of $P(\eta (t))$?

Comment: That's how the paper defines the probability density function of white noise. In other words, given an observation of the white noise $\eta(\cdot,\omega)$ for $\omega \in \Omega$, the "likelihood" of this observation is computed by the formula above. That's how  I interpret it

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/White_noise_analysis  https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/White_noise                           
These might help clarify.  My working with white noise has always been mathematical.

Comment: The formula $P(\eta (t))=$ is weird to me.  $\eta (t)$ is an element of a stochastic process.  $P(\eta (t))$ is a number, but the right hand side contains the integral of a stochastic process, so it is not a number.

Comment: I know it's weird -- I presume these come from physics which is why I'm looking for more rigorous theory on this. The right hand side, for a fixed sample of a stochastic process, is a number so I don't see what's inconsistent

Comment: Your notation still doesn't look right.  On the right hand side you have a fixed sample for $\eta(t)$ - which sample?  On the left hand side you have $P(\eta (t))$, which is in itself not well defined, since $\eta (t)$ is not discrete, so intrinsically $P(\eta (t))=0$.  You need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: OK. Left hand side is the PDF, not probability that $\eta(t,\omega) = \eta^*(t)$ for some function $\eta^*(t)$. Right hand side would have $\eta(t)$ replaced by $\eta^*(t)$ which is now a deterministic function. Is this still not clear??

Comment: Notation is now clear.  You need to explain relationship between $t$ in $P(\eta (t))$and $t_f$ and $t_i$.  Also $\eta ^*(t)$ needs to be defined.

Comment: Defining $P(\eta (t))$ as you have is still very confusing.  If $\eta (t)$ is a Gaussian noise process, then its PDF is the usual Gaussian ($\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$) and the major questions involve correlation or spectrum.

Comment: I agree that the notation is a bit strange. As a minimum, the upper limit in the integral should perhaps be $t$ (variable) instead of $t_f$ (value), so that both sides are functions of $t$. Also, upper case P is usually reserved for probability (as opposed to probability density $p$), so I would replace it with $p$. Then $p(\eta(t))$ is the probability density of the variate $\eta$ at time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Notation in the given expression aside, here is an attempt at interpreting it in relation to infinite-dimensional distributions, as mentioned in your first paragraph.

(Real) Gaussians with the given time-independent mean and delta-correlated covariance define a stationary process, i.e., independent of $t_i$. For any pair $(t_i,t_j)$, the two associated Gaussian variates $\eta_i=\eta(t_i)$ and $\eta_j\equiv\eta(t_j)$ are uncorrelated r.v. Hence, being Gaussians, they are mutually independent, so that their joint 2-dimensional probability density is their product
\begin{equation}
p(\eta_i,\eta_j;t_i,t_j) \propto \exp \left ( -\frac{\eta^2_1}{2\sigma^2_1} \right ) \cdot \exp \left  ( - \frac{\eta^2_2}{2\sigma^2_2} \right ) = \exp \left ( -\frac{\eta^2_1+\eta^2_2}{2D} \right )
\end{equation}
with $\sigma^2_1=\sigma^2_2 = E(\eta^2_1)=E(\eta^2_2) = D$ (taking $t=t^\prime$ above)  because $E(\eta_1)=E(\eta_2)=0$. 
Repeating and extending this for $3, 4, \ldots, n < \infty$ time points, one gets a (finite) $n$-dimensional hierarchy of $n$-dimensional joint Gaussian density functions. For continuous $t$, one can let $n$ approach infinite, thus producing an infinite-dimensional joint pdf (i.e., for all uncountable infinite $t$ within $[t_i,t_f]$ or $[-\infty,+\infty]$) and hence a stochastic process as a probability functional on $t$. In general, this requires all 2-, 3-, ..., $n$-point correlations to be specified and known (a serious difficulty in practice). For real Gaussians, only the two-point correlations are necessary and sufficient to define the process completely.

Returning to the formula in your post, since all $\eta_i$ are uncorrelated no matter how small the mutual distances $|t_i-t_j|$, one can take them arbitrarily close. Thus, $\eta^2_1+\eta^2_2+\ldots + \eta^2_n$ in the numerator of the exponential (in the extension of the expression above to $n$ dimensions) approaches a Riemannian sum and becomes an integral over $t$ when considering all points $t$ in a given interval $[t_i,t_f]$.